# C++17 POSIX Semaphore or condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization, posix

I am working on a project that includes event handling. I have access to a g++-9, C++17 (also possible C++20) environment.

I require the behavior of a semaphore. My **event handler**, pushes the event in a queue, to be processed by another thread (**event processor**). The **event handler** needs to be extremely lightweight to not miss fast occurring events. So I plan to just enqueue and increment the semaphore in the **event handler**, then do the load work in the **event processor**, decrementing the semaphore. (Avoiding busy waiting in the **event processor**, which will always be running.)

This is very easy using POSIX semaphore, however I also read that semaphores are implementable using condition_variables, counters, unique_locks, mutex' in C++. I wonder is it worth the trouble just to write C++ style to achieve simple POSIX semaphore behavior. More importantly, which one is faster ? Which is the better option for me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be trivial to try both approaches, run benchmarks and figure out "which one is faster" on your hardware. This is not something for which "which one is faster" will give you the same answer on every hardware platform on every operating system used in the entire world, today.

Comment: Why tag C? C++ looks good enough

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tagged it because posix libraries used more in C programs. Maybe somebody could provide more insight about them about the question. But you are right, it is a bit trivial.

Comment: That depends on your queue design. If it requires locking, semaphores probably won’t give you any benefit, while conditional variables are C++-native so are probably the way to go. But if you can implement your queue as lock-free, using semaphores (or even raw futexes on Linux) may give better performance. Still, benchmarking required.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab an off-the-shelf C++ "thread-safe queue" object and let it do the dirty work for you.  Correct implementations of this sort of thing have already been done (to death ...).

Read discussions like this:  https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/.